# How can I enable tab navigation for custom form elements in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, custom-controls

Safari defaults to only visit form elements when using the tab key for navigation. When using custom form elements, such as the [jQuery UI Selectmenu](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/), these elements are igonered when navigating through the form fields. How can I include custom form elements in navigation using the tab key without changing the default setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an `input` element right before the *jQuery Selectmenu*, and add an event handler to it so once it gets focus, it sets focus to the *jQuery Selectmenu*. Then use this CSS to hide the input box you added: `position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px;`

```
$('input.hiddenInput').focus(function(){
   var cameFrom = $('#myForm').data('lastIn');

   //check whether it came from the jQuery select menu
   if(cameFrom != 'jquery-ui-element'){
       $('jquery-ui-element').focus();
   } else {
       //focus previous sibling
       var inp = $('input');
       var index = inp.index(this);
       var prev = inp[index-1];
       prev.focus();
   }
});
```

Edit: To prevent being focused again after *shift + tab* you can do something like this.

```
$('#myForm input').focusout(function () {
   $('#myForm').data('lastIn', $(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: I like it :) However, it breaks shift-tabbing, as the element prior to the selectmenu is the select element, bouncing focus back to the selectmennu. I'm working on a solution now.

Comment: @Jørgen Can you check now. I have edited the post with a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't go quite for this solution, but you got me on the way, so I'm accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution I ended up with:

```
select{
  display: block !important;
  left: -9999;
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

I you set top: -9999, the page will scroll to the top when the element gets focus, so I skipped that. I reuse the original select elements that the selectmenu plugin is applied to. The important statements are used to override the element styles applied by the plugin.

The selectmenu plugin automatically sets focus to the a element, so that no javascript is needed in order to put focus on the custom dropdown when the select item is focused. However, this makes it impossible to tab backwards (with shift), as this will change focus from the custom element to the original element, which sets focus back to the custom element.

I solved this issue like this:

```
$('.ui-selectmenu').on('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.shiftKey && e.keyKode === 9){
    var all = $(':input'),
        el = $(this).parent().prev('select'),
        i = all.index(el);
    all.eq(i).focus();
});
```

Here I store all the inputs in a variable, find my select element, and set focus to the previous element.